# Finding schema from XML message, generate class and deserialize in JAVA from XML

Tags: java, xml, xsd, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I'm fairly new with JAVA and encountered a very specific problem:

I have a web service which return regularly XML messages.
I want to be able to deserialize this message into a JAVA object but i don't know how to proceed further...

This is a basic xml message i receive :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ds:tfmDataService
  xmlns:ds="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:tfmdataservice"
  xmlns="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:tfmdataservice"
  xmlns:fdm="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:flightdata"
  xmlns:nxce="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:tfmdatacoreelements"
  xmlns:nxcm="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:flightdatacommonmessages"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:tfmdataservice TFMData_Service.xsd">
  <fltdOutput>
    <fdm:fltdMessage acid="UAL1252" airline="UAL" arrArpt="KIAH" cdmPart="true" depArpt="KSAT" fdTrigger="FD_FLIGHT_MODIFY_MSG" flightRef="125539563" msgType="FlightModify" sensitivity="A" sourceFacility="UAL" sourceTimeStamp="2020-01-27T09:32:11Z">
      <fdm:ncsmFlightModify>
        <nxcm:qualifiedAircraftId>
          <nxce:aircraftId>UAL1252</nxce:aircraftId>
          <nxce:computerId>
            <nxce:facilityIdentifier>UAL</nxce:facilityIdentifier>
          </nxce:computerId>
          <nxce:igtd>2020-01-27T23:30:00Z</nxce:igtd>
          <nxce:departurePoint>
            <nxce:airport>KSAT</nxce:airport>
          </nxce:departurePoint>
          <nxce:arrivalPoint>
            <nxce:airport>KIAH</nxce:airport>
          </nxce:arrivalPoint>
        </nxcm:qualifiedAircraftId>
        <nxcm:airlineData>
          <nxcm:flightStatusAndSpec>
            <nxcm:flightStatus>FILED</nxcm:flightStatus>
            <nxcm:aircraftModel>B739</nxcm:aircraftModel>
            <nxcm:aircraftspecification aircraftEngineClass="JET" numberOfAircraft="1">B739</nxcm:aircraftspecification>
          </nxcm:flightStatusAndSpec>
          <nxcm:eta etaType="SCHEDULED" timeValue="2020-01-28T00:28:00Z"/>
          <nxcm:etd etdType="SCHEDULED" timeValue="2020-01-27T23:42:00Z"/>
          <nxcm:flightTimeData airlineInTime="2020-01-28T00:37:00Z" airlineOffTime="2020-01-27T23:42:00Z" airlineOnTime="2020-01-28T00:28:00Z" airlineOutTime="2020-01-27T23:30:00Z" flightCreation="2020-01-26T23:30:38Z" originalArrival="2020-01-28T00:28:00Z" originalDeparture="2020-01-27T23:42:00Z"/>
          <nxcm:diversionIndicator>NO_DIVERSION</nxcm:diversionIndicator>
          <nxcm:rvsmData currentCompliance="true" equipped="true" futureCompliance="true"/>
          <nxcm:arrivalFixAndTime arrTime="2020-01-28T00:03:10Z" fixName="GMANN"/>
        </nxcm:airlineData>
      </fdm:ncsmFlightModify>
    </fdm:fltdMessage>
  </fltdOutput>
</ds:tfmDataService>
```

So first i don't get how i'm supposed to find the schema location since the adress is urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:tfmdataservice TFMData_Service.xsd

I have no clue on how to get this schema description since this adress doesnt looks like a http adress and so i'm not able to extract the schema description since i don't know where to download it.

I understood that i need this schema in order to generate my java class that will be used to deserialize the message into a JAVA object. 
Is it possible to generate the object on the fly when receiving this type of message or do i really need to first generate the classes to deserialized my messages ?

Then if i'm able to get the xsd describing any xml message received, how am i supposed to generate the code necessary for data deserialization ? How does it work ? Are there specific tools to do that ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So first i don't get how i'm supposed to find the schema location since the adress is urn:us:gov:dot:faa:atm:tfm:tfmdataservice TFMData_Service.xsd
>
> I have no clue on how to get this schema description since this adress doesnt looks like a http adress and so i'm not able to extract the schema description since i don't know where to download it.

Not all schemas are in the public domain. Often, you need to sign up with the provider organisation before you can get the schemas and/or API specifications.

> I understood that i need this schema in order to generate my java class that will be used to deserialize the message into a JAVA object. Is it possible to generate the object on the fly when receiving this type of message or do i really need to first generate the classes to deserialized my messages ?

Java can parse XML without using a schema, but I don't recommend it for this scenario (receiving data from a government API). If there is a schema available - and I would be very surprised if there is not - then you should use it. It will simplify your Java code, and you also have the option of validating against the schema while parsing.

> Then if i'm able to get the xsd describing any xml message received, how am i supposed to generate the code necessary for data deserialization ? How does it work ? Are there specific tools to do that ?

That is an easy question to answer using your favourite search engine. Search for 'JAXB'.